# set the time property as the m-dimension of postgis geometry or as a separate attribute

Tags: postgresql, geometry, geospatial, postgis, multi-index

Basic version info first:

```sh
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-1.pgdg18.04+1)
postgis          | 3.1.1
```

**My purpose of using spatial database is to quickly query the GPS trajectories within the `specified time scope` and `space boundary`.** Currently, basic information about my data is as follow:

```sql
-- geometry table column (there are 50,000 rows in table mpart5w-wkt)
test=# \d "mpart5w-wkt"
                       Table "public.mpart5w-wkt"
  Column   |            Type            | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------+----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 driver_id | character varying          |           |          |
 order_id  | character varying          |           |          |
 geom      | geometry(LineStringM,4326) |           |          |
Indexes:
    "mpart5w-wkt_driver_id_idx" btree (driver_id)
    "mpart5w-wkt_geom_idx" gist (geom gist_geometry_ops_nd)


-- meta info
test=# select * from geometry_columns where f_table_name='mpart5w-wkt';

 f_table_catalog | f_table_schema | f_table_name | f_geometry_column | coord_dimension | srid |    type
-----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+------+-------------
 test            | public         | mpart5w-wkt  | geom              |               3 | 4326 | LINESTRINGM
(1 row)


-- sample data: LINESTRING M (lon lat timestamp)
test=# select st_astext(geom) from "mpart5w-wkt" limit 1;

 LINESTRING M (104.04538 30.70745 1538402919,104.04538 30.70744 1538402928,104.04537 30.70745 1538402938,104.04536 30.70743 1538402948,104.04537 30.7074 1538402958, ...)
```

Just to emphasize, `geom` is geometry type of (LineStringM, 4326). GIS index has been built on geom column.

**The first question is whether the M-dimension supports multi-index?**

I checked the official manual about [multi-index](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_usage.html#brin_indexes) , it shows that we can get a 4D-dimensional `BRIN` index using the 4D operator class:

```sql
CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename]
    USING BRIN ([geome_col] brin_geometry_inclusion_ops_4d);
```

At the same time, we can get the an n-dimensional `gist` index for the geometry type using this syntax:

```sql
CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename] USING GIST ([geometryfield] gist_geometry_ops_nd);
```

So, I guess it's helpful to build 4D `gist` index as long as ZM dimensions are provided.

In most description of [functions](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force2D.html), "This function supports 3d and will not drop the z-index." is mentioned without mentioning m-index, while I have no more idea about the m-index.

After all, there is no solid evidence shows whether the M-dimension supports multi-index and how to use multi-index on M-dimension.

Maybe I should create table like this, so that I need not to deal with the M dimension any more?

```sql
create table "part5w-wkt"(
    driver_id varchar,
    order_id varchar,
    geom geometry(Linestring, 4326), 
    min_time timestamp,
    max_time timestamp
);

-- example (both start_time and end_time are parameters)
select * from "mpart5w-wkt" 
where st_intersects(
    geom, 
    ST_MakeEnvelope(104.067, 30.657, 104.083, 30.671, 4326)
) and (
    (min_time < start_time and start_time < max_time) 
     or
    (min_time < end_time and end_time < max_time)
)
```

**The second question is how to use 2D-index with boundary box?**

After all, there is no evidence shows that using a m-dimension with gist index is more convenient than using 2D geometry with a separate attribute about time. So, I decide to make a test on 2D-index firstly.

```sql
-- test 1
explain analyze
select count(order_id) from "mpart5w-wkt" 
where st_intersects(
    st_force2d(geom), 
    ST_MakeEnvelope(104.067, 30.657, 104.083, 30.671, 4326)
);

-- test 2
explain analyze
select count(order_id) from "mpart5w-wkt" 
where st_intersects(
    st_force2d(geom), 
    st_geometryfromtext(
        'polygon((104.067 30.671, 104.083 30.671, 104.083 30.657, 104.067 30.657, 104.067 30.671))', 
        4326
    )
);

-- test 3
explain analyze
select count(order_id) from "mpart5w-wkt" 
where st_intersects(
    st_force2d(geom), 
    'SRID=4326;polygon((104.067 30.671, 104.083 30.671, 104.083 30.657, 104.067 30.657, 104.067 30.671))'::geometry
);

-- almost the same result
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=547292.05..547292.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=817.698..824.482 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=547291.84..547292.05 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=817.380..824.451 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=546291.84..546291.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=804.706..804.707 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "mpart5w-wkt"  (cost=0.00..546291.83 rows=2 width=19) (actual time=97.585..803.734 rows=4394 loops=3)
                     Filter: st_intersects(st_force2d(geom), '0103000020E610000001000000050000003F355EBA49045A40D578E92631A83E403F355EBA49045A40B29DEFA7C6AB3E405A643BDF4F055A40B29DEFA7C6AB3E405A643BDF4F055A40D578E92631A83E403F355EBA49045A40D578E92631A83E40'::geometry)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 12272
 Planning Time: 0.268 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 17
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 2.771 ms, Inlining 99.859 ms, Optimization 117.378 ms, Emission 74.123 ms, Total 294.132 ms
 Execution Time: 825.745 ms
(14 rows)
```

However, the test shows that results are almost the same and the spatial index didn't work even thouth I have done many different tests. Removing the st_force2d() function got a lower efficiency.

The efficiency if reffered to be lower on the same work with addtional time constraints.

By the way, **Which of 4326 and 3857 should I use as the SRID to store GPS trajectory geometry if lon-lat boundary box is used frequently while computing distance is needed at the same time?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use `ST_DWitthin`? Since you're looking for geometries that lie inside a given area, might be relevant :)

Comment: or maybe creating the index using the ST_Force2D:: `CREATE INDEX idx_part5w ON "part5w-wkt" USING gist (ST_Force2D(geom) gist_geometry_ops_nd);` Sorry if I get your post wrong.. it's kinda long :D

Comment: emmm, I tried ST_DWitthin as your suggestion just now, it seems no different between the result of `ST_DWitthin(geom1, geom2, 0)` and `ST_Intersects(geom1, geom2)`, both of their result count num is 13183.

Comment: It is still not using the index?

Comment: yes, no index used

Comment: puzzling. can you check this fiddle? I tried to reproduce your environment and the index is being used: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f58a356bc11bda750303a9b4807b814

Comment: Your suggestion did really works! It takes me some time to get familiar with stackoverflow website, I added the result and some more questions through `post my own answer`, I‘m looking forward to your suggestion~

Comment: well, you really don't ask further questions in a answer to your own question. And you definitely do not post an answer with somebody else's answer ;) If you have multiple questions, you have to create multiple posts, otherwise the post gets long, confusing and pretty much useless for other users. Welcome to SO and happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the index to sort its records already using `geom` as 2D by means of using the function `ST_Force2D` in the index creation, so that the database doesn't need to do it in query time:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_part5w_wkt_geom ON "part5w-wkt" 
USING gist (ST_Force2D(geom) gist_geometry_ops_nd);
```

It will have a similar effect if you just omit the `ST_Force2D` in the `CREATE INDEX` as long as you also don't use it later on in the `WHERE` clause. Long story short: the way columns are indexed and how they're queried have to match, otherwise the index is probably not going to be used.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=451a79944a369f0ef03c49ba55fffea5)

Comment: It's ok to work in 2D-index!!! Is that means I should use st_3dintersects/st_3dDwithin with a M-dimension or i should set the time attribute as Z-dimension?
What's more, I should build both 2D-index and 3D-index if the `time` property is needed as a part of query condition at the same time, is that right?

Comment: @qizidog aren't you using `min_time` and `max_time` to store the time range of your trajectory? If so, I see no reason to extract it in query time from the LineString. It is ok to have multiple indexes for a single column based on different application scenarios, but keep in mind that it slows down a bit any changes in the table (e.g. insert, update)

Comment: Ok, but if I set the `time` as m-dimension instead of z-dimension, does it work in multi-index? I haven't seen any introduction about this yet.

Comment: @qizidog yes, you can store time in the m dimension, as long as it is numeric, e.g. using `unix time`. Regarding performance, depending on the function you use, the index will be used no matter what you put in the z or m dimensions. In the end, they're just numbers.